# SAXParser with local XML file

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I've read several topic on how to read local XML file.

Most of them are using openRawResource(). However it's much more slower compared to getXML().

I wanted to use getXML for my project, it's there any way to use getXML with XMLReader.parse(), as SAX InputSource does not accept XmlResourceParser as parameter.

**Edit:** btw, when do the startElement endElement will be called? Is it right after XMLReader.parse? Is it possible to restart the parsing from the top when I read a certain value of attributes?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it(assume that you are keeping your xml in assets folder)

```
 InputStream response=context.getAssets().open("your.xml");
```

and then

```
  Xml.parse(response, Xml.Encoding.UTF_8,rootElement.getContentHandler());
```

Comment: Apparently I could not access the xml if I use the path "assets/your.xml" but it works if it's "your.xml"

Comment: Thanks for showing me the wrong part of the code.Fixed it.It was a copy paste error.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler(getApplicationContext());
            reader.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(getAssets().open("Getalloffersbyzipcoderesponse_xml.xml")));
        //  listView.setAdapter(new EventListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, myXMLHandler.getEventList()));
            listView.setAdapter(new OffersListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, myXMLHandler.getOffersList()));
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the 'getXML()'-function, you can check out this tutorial, whic show's how to use the 'XmlResourceParser'-Interface: [Link](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html)

Anothet way would be if you put the XML files in the '[openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int,%20android.util.TypedValue%29)'-method, which returns an 'InputStream' on a given Resource ID, which you can then pass to the normal 'SAXParser'.

Comment: I've seen many post telling that openRawResource is 10x slower than getXML, that's why I put this question up. Checking on the former link you provided :)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any difference but you can try and see wich one is faster...